# React Native obtaining TextInput value in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am currently learning how to use Redux after using vanilla React Native for some time. I am trying to understand how to store a `TextInput`'s value. Previously I would have simply stored the value in state. I have tried a few things including the code sample below.

Currently, `todoInput.value` is undefined. I have also tried directly assigning the `value` prop of the `TextInput` to a variable defined with `let` but this also stays undefined.

How can I alter the code so that the value of the `TextInput` is not undefined?

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addTodo } from '../actions';

const addNewTodo = (dispatch, value) => {
  dispatch(addTodo(value));
}

const AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let todoInput;

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput ref={inputRef => todoInput = inputRef} />
      <Button title="Add Todo" onPress={() => addNewTodo(dispatch, todoInput.value)}></Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default connect()(AddTodo);
```

Comment: In order to get a value from a `TextInput` ref, you need to use `todoInput._lastNativeText `

Comment: @PritishVaidya Thank you - that worked! But I'm still left with a few questions... why does the value prop return undefined? And is using _lastNativeText the best practice when it comes to obtaining the value in Redux?

Comment: Ideally, you should use the `onChangeText` prop and put the value in a component's `state`, and bind the `state value` to the once you `dispatch` the action. There are some methods defined for the `textInput` ref and maybe the `.value` is not one of them hence undefined.

Comment: @PritishVaidya Ah I see, that makes sense. Would you mind putting that recommended approach into an answer so I can select as best? A code example would really help me understand the theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a *stateful component* in order to pass the `value` to the component `state` so that it can be used in *multiple places*.

Based on your scenario (Assuming that the component is connected)

```
class AddTodo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todoInput: null
  }

  addNewTodo = () => {
    this.props.dispatch(addNewTodo(this.state.todoInput))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput onChangeText={text => this.setState({todoInput: text})} value={this.state.todoInput} {...{/*Other Props*/}}/>
        <Button title="Add Todo" onPress={this.addNewTodo}></Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```